# netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection 2" admin=DISABLED

Tags: c#, interface, adapter, netsh

I want to disable all network adapters:

I saw that it can be done via system command netsh.

When I run the following command i got an error.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection 2" admin=DISABLED
Area is not an acceptable value for connect.
The parameter is incorrect.
```

It seems that the command line parser could not get the spacing. The same happens if using single quote (instead of double quotes).

i need your help gurus.

By the way, my code is C#, I tried many examples from the web and none of worked.

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = 
       new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(
               "netsh", 
               "interface set interface name=\"" + interfaceName + "\" admin=enabled");
 System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process(); 
  p.StartInfo = psi; 
  bool result = p.Start();
```

Comment: You say you use c#, can you show the code that builds the command and executes it?

Comment: System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface set interface name=\"" + interfaceName + "\" admin=enabled");
            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            p.StartInfo = psi;
            bool result = p.Start();

Answer (score 1):

I use

```
netsh interface set interface "Local Area Connection 2" ENABLED
```

it works fine for me and enables "Local Area Connection 2"

probably you might use this way with your code, it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ----------------------------------------------
echo Restarting network interfaces
echo ----------------------------------------------

netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces

for /F "tokens=1-3,4*" %%I in ('netsh interface ipv4 show interfaces ^| find /I "CONNECTED" ^| find /I /V "DISCONNECTED" ^| find /I /V "LOOPBACK"') do (
    echo.&echo - Restarting #%%I [%%M] ...
    netsh interface set interface name="%%M" admin=disabled >nul 2>&1
    ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 >nul 2>&1
    netsh interface set interface name="%%M" admin=enabled >nul 2>&1
    ping -n 1 127.0.0.1 >nul 2>&1
    if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        echo   +++ OK +++
    ) else (
        echo   --- NOK ---
    )
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).